# Share tokens between multiple applications ADAL android

Tags: android, share, token, adal

I am using the ADAL library to authenticate users in an application.

I was wondering if there was a way to share the auth token with another application so that a user can login in one app and doesn't have to do it again in the other one.

I have tried saving the token in an account in the android account manager but it's kind of messy and it feels like there should be a more ADAL way to do it.

It seems like there is a way to share the TokenCacheStore, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two application shares the same client ids, and you defined the android:sharedUserId in your application manifest, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Yes, figured out you just have to give the 2 apps the same sharedUserId and setup the AuthenticationContext so that they use the same shared preferences file